# Can't require() default export value in Babel 6.x

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In Babel 5.x, I can write the following code:

**app.js**

```
export default function (){}
```

**index.js**

```
require('babel/register');
require('./app')();
```

Then, I can run `node index.js` with no errors. However, using Babel 6.x, running the following code

**index.es6.js**

```
require('babel-core/register');
require('./app')();
```

results in an error

> require(...) is not a function

I want to know why?

Comment: Do you have a `.babelrc`? Are you specifying Babel options somewhere? I ask because Babel 6 doesn't transpile anything by default and you are not specifying the `es2015` preset in the code you have posted.

Comment: @IgorRaush I really have a `.babelrc`, the others es6 script is running normally

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions. `babel` is for questions for a *Python library* with said name.

Comment: Just don't export a function from `app.js`, but run it right away

Comment: @FelixKling sorry, I don't know the same name also in python...

Answer (score 197, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You have to use

```
const app = require('./app').default;
app();
```

**Explanation**

Babel 5 used to have a compatibility hack for `export default`: if a module contained only one export, and it was a default export, it was assigned to `module.exports`. So, for example, your module **app.js**

```
export default function () {}
```

would be transpiled to this

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports["default"] = function () {};

module.exports = exports["default"];
```

This was done *purely* for compatibility with `require`-ing Babel-transpiled modules (like you are doing). It was also inconsistent; if a module contained both named and default exports, it could not be `require`-d.

In reality, according to the ES6 module spec, a default export is *no different* than a named export with the name `default`. It is just syntactic sugar which can be statically resolved at compile time, so this

```
import something from './app';
```

is the same as this

```
import { default as something } from './app';
```

That being said, it appears that Babel 6 decided to drop the interoperability hack when transpiling modules. Now, your module **app.js** is transpiled as

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

exports.default = function () {};
```

As you see, no more assignment to `module.exports`. To `require` this module, you need to do

```
const app = require('./app').default;
app();
```

Or, more concisely, and closer to your original code:

```
require('./app').default();
```

Comment: For me `require('./app').default;` worked. `default()` returned `undefined`

Comment: @thinklinux, `require(...).default` gives a reference to the exported function. `default()` calls it. If your function does not return anything (or is empty), then, of course, the result will be `undefined`.

Comment: `require('path').default()` doesn't work, `require('path').default` works for me

Comment: You should use `require('./app').default;` If you export an object instead of a function.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify that `require('./app').default` is usually what you want. For the original question, `require('./app').default()` works because the OP was importing a function and executing it immediately.

Answer (score 10):

Just to follow up with the correct answer above.

If you wanna use default export behavior of `babel@5`, you can try [babel-plugin-add-module-exports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) plugin.

It's working pretty well for me.

Answer (score 5):

If this doesn't work

```js
require('./app').default()
```

use

```js
require('./app').default
```

Without the function call at the end.

Comment: As Igor says in the comment above (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x#comment60540767_33705077) the first of your examples will call the function whilst the second will give it a reference