# VueJS data() not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a VueJS app but I am failing even with the simplest examples.
I am using Laravel 5.3 with pre-built support for VueJS (version 1, I tried version 2 as well).

Here is my Example.vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="profile">
        {{ name }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                name: 'John Doe'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And here is the main code

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

This is the error that shows up everytime in console:

*[Vue warn]: Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in component )*

Any ideas whats wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `script` tags instead of `export default` use:

```
module.exports = {
  data() {
    return { counter: 1 }
  }
}
```

This should work for you

Answer (score 1):

Call the component inside your template

```js
Vue.component('example', {
  template: `<div class="profile">{{ name }}</div>`,
  data () {
return {
  name: 'John Doe'
}
  }
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"><example></example></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it works this way. But I would really like to use 'single file component'

Comment: this is exactly the same, no? import the single file component and replace the components options with your imported component name

Comment: Well, no. [This](http://vuejs.org/guide/single-file-components.html) is what I am trying to achieve, and [this](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html) is what you showed me. It's not much of a difference but you know, details matter :D

Comment: are you using webpack or browserify?

Comment: Yes, Laravel has got all of this prepared

Comment: and you are running a npm command to bundle your js file? (just checking)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load the component 'example' from that file but you didn't give a name to it. You should use:

```html
<script>
   export default {
     name: 'example',
     data() {
       return {
         name: 'John Doe'
       }
     }
   }
</script>
```

Or load the component the following way (not sure if extension .vue is needed):

```js
require('./exmaple').default();
```

If you are using Babel you can also load the components without giving them a name using this syntax:

```js
import Example from ./example
```

Also checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x) to get some more info in case you use Babel