# ES6 dynamic imports and instanciation of classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to figure out how to perform dynamic import of classes in ES6 one the server side (node.js with Babel). 
I would like to have some functionalities similar to what reflection offers in Java. The idea is to import all the classes in a specific folder and instanciate them dynamically.

So for example  I could have multiple classes declared in a folder like the one below :

```
export default class MyClass {

   constructor(somevar) {
       this._somevar = somevar
   }

   //...
   //some more instance level functions here
}
```

and then somewhere else in my app's code I could have a function that finds out all the classes in a specific folder and tries to instanciate them  :

```
//somewhere else in my app
instanciationFunction(){

   //find all the classes in a specific folder
   var classFiles = glob.sync(p + '/path_to_classes/**/*.js', {
       nodir: true
   });

   _.each(classFiles, async function (file) {
       console.log(file);

       var TheClass = import(file);
       var instance = new TheClass();

       //and then do whatever I want with that new instance

   });
}
```

I've tried doing it with require but I get errors. Apparently the constructor cant be found.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic importing is pretty much the opposite of what ES6 `import` was designed for.

Comment: What solution do I have then ?

Comment: What is that `import` function you are using in your second snippet?

Comment: @Bergi it was just an example inspired by some examples I saw online

Comment: You probably [are looking for `TheClass = require(file).default`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33704714/1048572) and should drop the `async`.

Answer (score 1):

ES module definitions are declarative, and the current direction tools are taking is the path where dependencies are determined during parse (via static analysis), waaay before any of the code is executed. This means dynamic and conditional imports go against the said path. It's not like in Node where imports are determined on execution, upon executing `require`.

If you want dynamic, runtime imports, consider taking a look at [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs). If you're familiar with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), it takes the same concept, but expands it to [multiple module formats](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), including ES6. It has [`SystemJS.import`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsimportmodulename--normalizedparentname---promisemodule) which appears to do what you want, plus handles the path resolution that you're currently doing.

Alternatively, if your intention is to shed off excess code, consider using [Rollup](http://rollupjs.org/). It will analyze code for you and only include code that's actually used. That way, you don't need to manually do conditional loading.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preprocess with babel, because they are not yet a part of node (for that matter, neither are *static imports* - node uses *require*).

https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node

steps:

pre

`npm i -D babel-cli` or `npm i -D babel`

1

`npm i -D babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node`

2

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

ready, go!

`babel-node test_import.js` for babel-cli, or for raw babel:

a

(edit) package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "pretest": "babel test_imports.js -o dist/test_imports.js",
  "test": "node dist/test_imports.js"
//...
```

b

`node test`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same usecase and i managed to dynamically load and instantiate default exported classes using:

```
const c = import("theClass.js")
const i = new c.default();
```

using node v16.4.0