# Require not working in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm new to vue trying to build a simple SPA with `Vue` without `vue-router`. Following the `vue-2.0-simple-routing-example` I'm just trying to serve pages via `require(dynamicPathToFile+'.vue')`. But it's not working.

This works:

**Main.Vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

**Main.JS**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './main.vue'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render (h) {
    return h(App)
  }
})
```

but why doesn't this work?

**Main.JS**

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render (h) {
    return h(require('./main.vue'))
  }
})
```

It compiles just fine, but in my javascript console I get

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <Root>
```

Nothing displays

how do i get it to work so I can dynamically require a page, rather than import it at the top?

Comment: Try `require('./main.vue').default`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x

Comment: @thanksd cool! That works. But why is it needed? https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-2.0-simple-routing-example seems to not need it.

Comment: Different versions of babel handle the `default` export differently, so I'm assuming its because of your version of babel

Comment: @thanksd makes sense thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't require() default export value in Babel 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)

Comment: Show Folder Structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to include .default because I was working with a newer (fixed) version of Babel