# Vue inline template not finding methods or data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Normally using Vue as an out of the box solution with Laravel so it just 'works'.

I am adding it now to a WordPress build but have an issue with an inline template.

Every looks fine, but it will not do anything in the mounted method and says that any data or methods are undefined, almost likes its not properly loading the component.

Here is the basic HTML:

```
<tabbed-panels class="component tabPanels" inline-template>
    <div>
        <div class="tabPanels__controls-control" v-on:click="changeTab(1)"></div>
    </div>
</tabbed-panels>
```

tabbed-panels.js:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            activeTab: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeTab(id) {
            this.activeTab = id;
        }
    },
    ready() {
        console.log('foo');
    } 
}
```

Import statement:

```
Vue.component('tabbed-panels', require('./tabbed-panels.js'));
```

Any idea where this could be going wrong? Normal single file .vue components work fine but not possible for the content.

Comment: If you assign `require('./tabbed-panels.js')` to a variable, does it contain anything?

Comment: @RoyJ I console log'd it and it returns an object called default with the various methods, data and mounted objects.

Comment: Please, provide the version of Vue you used

Comment: Probably needs to be `Vue.component('tabbed-panels', require('./tabbed-panels.js').default));`

Comment: @thanksd That done the trick. Never seen that mentioned before so i'll look it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't require() default export value in Babel 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)