# Why does require not behave the same as import when same structure is given

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It seems I have a fundamental lack of understanding when it comes to `import` vs `require`. From what I've read I know the difference is that `require` is based on a module loaders like `CommonJS` while import is actually an ES6 feature.

Assuming the following:

```
import ExamplePost from 'example-post.md'
```

This is an example import with [MDX JS](https://mdxjs.com) as appropriate loader and I 
 set this in my React render function like:

```
render () {
  return <ExamplePost />
}
```

The above works perfectly fine, but
as I want to dynamically load different Markdown files and I have read that ES6 `import` are static I intended to go like:

```
let postName = 'example-post'
const ExamplePost = require(`${postName}.md`)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I am getting: `ExamplePost is not defined`

I'm setting both examples at the top of the document. I also inspected both versions and I can see a difference in the outcome:

ES6 import returns: `[Function]`

Require returns: `Object [Module] { default: [Function] }`

Help to get me on the right track on why the require above does not work the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `import` the default export of module and `require` the module itself.

```
const ExamplePost = require(`${postName}.md`).default
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Also check [Can't require() default export value in Babel 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)

Comment: Thanks Ujin, this has been a very helpful answer