# How do I easily change context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, storybook

I'm using storybook to mock pages of my app. I have an idea where I wrap storybook with one context for mock data, and then when I run the real application I can give it another context where it'll get data from an API.

How can I do this with useContext? My issue is that useContext requires me to import a context which will need to be easily swapped for another one. Because the mock context and live context are in different folders, import paths will be different.

In my storybook config:

```
export const Context = React.createContext();

addDecorator(story => (
  <Context.Provider value="hello!">
    {story()}
  </Context.Provider>
))
```

In my component:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react;
import { Context } from 'path/to/context';

const value = useContext(Context)
```

Comment: You could still use your `Context` both in the real app and in storybook, but in the real app you use a `Provider` with a `value` more suited for your app.

Comment: @Tholle both storybook and the real app will use the same `Context` but I pass in a different value to each one?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea. In the storybook you could have a provider with `<Context.Provider value="hello!">`, and in the app `<Context.Provider value="something else!">`.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're bundling with Webpack with Babel, this might help. Nevertheless, I think what you're looking for is an environment variable to conditionally do that swapping for you.

Note: the `process.env.NODE_ENV` are auto set if you config webpack `mode` to `development` or `production`. Otherwise, you can set it yourself with the `DefinePlugin()`.

[Webpack mode docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/)

**webpack.dev.js**

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"'
      }
    })
  ]
```

**webpack.prod.js**

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    })
  ]
```

Then you could do something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('./productionContext.js')
} else {
  require('./developmentContext.js')
}
```

[Answer on how to require default exports.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)