# Vue Component in big Laravel project not showing - no errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-6

Very strange occurrence I have here that is getting me crazy and keeping me out of sleep at night, and can't understand why this happens. Basically I have a running laravel project, quite big one. I have installed vue and after fighting a while, everything seems to have gone well, no errors in npm run dev or npm run production.
When I inspect my blade view in the browser I see the example component there, but it is just empty. [In this image a screenshot of the inspect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4cvD.jpg)

**app.js:**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component(
    'example',
    require('./components/Example.vue').default
    );
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'    
});
```

**Example.vue:**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an example component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see here above, I am using the default component layouts that come out of the box with vue/laravel, nothing esoteric. Odd enough, on the console, I don't receive any errors, but I also don't receive any message, and I also can't get to output "Component mounted" to the console.
I am using the  component on a laravel blade file like this.

```
<div id="app">
    <example></example>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Everything seems to be configured properly but  remains empty. Any ideas how I can further debug/investigate this issue? Can there be anything in laravel that stops the rendering or anything? There are quite some scripts and css loading but even when I remove them, nothing seems to change. I am currently developing on a **local homestead vagrant box with PHP 7.4.5 (cli), Composer 1.10.5, node v12.16.2, laravel/framework^6.0, laravel/ui^1.2, laravel-mix@1.7.2**. The project uses laravel6 thus the other versions accordingly. Many thanks.

Comment: Somewhere near the top of `app.js` try adding `console.log(document.getElementById('app'))` and then check what gets logged. You might have 2 elements with the id `app` and that logging should confirm which one Vue will see. It will also confirm that the code in that file is running at all. Maybe also log `app.$el` at the bottom, see which element that gives you.

Comment: No output at all. How can this be possible

Comment: Take a look in the *Network* tab and find the request that loads `app.js`. That should allow you to see what code is making it to the browser.

Comment: Cool. didn't know about that one. Well actually I can see a call to app.js and inside the app.js there's the function of my example component, but nothing is printed on the console.

function(t, e, n) {
    n(13),
    window.Vue = n(36),
    Vue.component("example", n(40).default);
    new Vue({
        el: "#app"
    })
}

Comment: Figuring out why there's no console logging mentioned in the `app.js` seems like something you should investigate further. It may just be caching or an unsaved file. However, just to test whether there are multiple elements with the id `app` you could try typing `document.querySelectorAll('#app')` directly into the console.

Comment: Definitely. But how Can I do that? :) 
`document.querySelectorAll('#app')` shows the following 
`NodeList [div#app]
0: div#app
length: 1
...etc etc...` So there seems to be something right?

Comment: In the console I see two things. first a `GET http://localhost.local/js/app.js` and then the `<div id="app">
app.js:1:117858
null`. Then inside the #app this seems OK: `innerHTML: "\n    <example></example>\n    \n"` but this looks strange: `innerText: "\n    \n    \n"` - The inner text should not be empty. but rather the content I put in Example Component. Also this might be weird
`isConnected: false` perhaps? Any clue? Thx

Comment: Another strange occurrence is that from my app.js things like `console.log('Printout test.');` are not shown on the console. Any suggestions on how I could proceed in the debugging are really appreciated.

Comment: If all were working correctly you wouldn't see `<example></example>` inside the `#app` element. Vue should replace those with your component's markup. What you're seeing currently is consistent with Vue doing nothing at all. As a test, could you put `<input :value="2">` inside the `#app` element, just above the `<example>` element? If Vue is running on that template it should populate the input with the number 2. If Vue isn't doing anything you'll end up with an empty input.

Comment: As for the console logging not showing up, I see two possibilities. As you observed earlier, the logging code did not appear in the built version of `app.js`. So either something is stripping it out or there's a more general caching problem. To eliminate the first option you could simply try making other changes to see if they make it into the built `app.js`. e.g. Change the `el: '#app'` line to something else (it doesn't matter what) just to see whether it has any impact on the file you see in the *Network* tab. Assuming those changes don't show up either, there must be a caching problem.

Comment: OK I managed to print output in the console. And Modifying the app.js with the following code `const example = require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default;
console.log(example);
Vue.component('example-component', example);` shows _undefined_ and also the warning `[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <example-component> - did you register the component correctly?` Despite that in the network tab I can see a call to app.js. Also, not sure if it's related but had to change **sass from 8.0.0 to 7.3.1** because of this issue: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/761

Comment: It may be that you need to drop the `.default` part to get this to work. Try logging `require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue')` without the `.default`, see what's in there. Whether you need the `.default` will depend on how the modules are being transpiled, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x

Comment: **YES!** Not sure I am yet understanding the why, but it works! That was the issue in my case. Truly thanks a lot!!!