# React: error when integrate component without JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm newby in React JS and I trying to integrate the component https://github.com/AndrewRedican/react-json-editor-ajrm/ in my App without using JSX.

The project not use import syntax like `import Component from library` but use the the syntax like const Component = require(library)`.

There is the snippet where the component is integrated:

```js
  makeMessageElement() {
    const textFieldOptions = {
      width: '100%',
      placeholder: 'Enter message',
      value: this.state.message,
      onChange: (event, value) => {
        this.setState({
          message: value
        })
      }
    }
 
    return React.createElement(JSONInput, textFieldOptions, null)
  }
```

When I trying `const JSONInput = require('react-json-editor-ajrm')`, I get the message :

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

When I trying `const {JSONInput} = require('react-json-editor-ajrm')`, I get the same message.

When I trying `import JSONInput from "react-json-editor-ajrm";`, I get the message :

> Uncaught Component.js:8
> import JSONInput from "react-json-editor-ajrm";
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

So, what is the right way to import the library please ?

Comment: what about import {JSONInput} from 'react-json-editor-ajrm'

Comment: I get the same message than `import JSONInput from "react-json-editor-ajrm";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try the require(path).default:

```
const JSONInput = require('react-json-editor-ajrm').default
```

and for [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this :

```
import * as JSONInput from "react-json-editor-ajrm";
```

or

```
import { JSONInput } from "react-json-editor-ajrm";
```

If it doesn't work, just tell me and we'll look more into this together :)

Edit for the require :

```
const JSONInput = require('react-json-editor-ajrm').default
```

Comment: I have the following message: `import * as JSONInput from "react-json-editor-ajrm"; SyntaxError: Unexpected token *`. I think that the project is not configured to use syntax `import ...`. (e.g. Webpack). But  I would'nt reconfigure the project just to import this comporent and use component. If there is another way...

Comment: Oh sry, did not see your answer. 

Try this maybe : const JSONInput = require('react-json-editor-ajrm').default