# Use of default with require function in vue.component function

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js, npm

when we are writing the code to import the Vue components in our app.js file then we have to write a function ->

```
    Vue.component('homepage-component',require('./components/HomepageComponent.vue').**default**);
```

here we have used "default" Now I don't know why we are using it.Please tell me what is the work of this **default** as I want to clear my concept

Comment: See this other [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33705077/6225326)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't require() default export value in Babel 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704714/cant-require-default-export-value-in-babel-6-x)